# Regular expression to validate zipcode/postal code

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I want to validate zipcode or pincode in address fields. that's why I am trying to write regular express which is just except `a-z` (upper and lower both), `0-9` numbers, round brackets (eg. `()`) and hyphen `-` and space. But some rules must be followed like single white space can not be on first position, two or more white space can not be allowed.

some of invalid entries

```
1254588
125  255
((125))  255
125--255
(125) (255)
125>2458
EL$ 2458
@L$ 2458
```

Comment: "Some rules" is a bit unspecific. Please explain the precise rules, then it's going to be easy to construct a suitable regex.

Comment: For your information :



  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15747087/regular-expression-to-verify-zip-code-and-checking-for-invalid-characters

Comment: List all the rules in detail, without that we're just guessing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If those are all the rules that matter, it's easy:

```
^                  # Start of string
(?! )              # First character mustn't be space
(?!.*  )           # No two spaces in a row
[A-Za-z0-9 ()-]*   # Match any number of these allowed characters
$                  # End of string
```

or, for JavaScript:

```
/^(?! )(?!.*  )[A-Za-z0-9 ()-]*$/
```

but I'm guessing that strings like `"))))(((("`, `"-------"`, `"A"` or even `""` shouldn't actually be matched, but are allowed by your rules.

Comment: thanks @tim pietzcher, your doubt is very true. and I also don't want this values. can you consider this in same expression?

Comment: @ManishSapkal: Yes, if you specify the exact rules that should be applied to the regex.

Comment: pietzcher, I want user can enter only valid zipcode which is as follows : (215) 45878, 2585 55 4587 ED 261-445589. means two space, hyphen, start/end round brackets in a row now allowed. A-Z (upper/lower) and 0-9 only allowed. initially it is acceptable for me.

Comment: These rules do not rule out `----` or `()()()` or `)a(` or `-( -)`... you need to be more precise than that.

Comment: pietzcher yes. But i can't do that, because I am not much aware with regex. can you help me out to do this?

Comment: You don't need to know regex, you need to define the problem exactly by stating the rules what strings may or may not match. I can then translate them to regex. Your question currently is like "Please nail this picture to this wall", and I could nail it upside-down, face-backwards in the lower left corner of the wall because you haven't said how exactly you want it hanged. Computers need precise instructions, and you can only give them precise instructions if the requirements are absolutely clear. In your case, they aren't.

Comment: @Pietzcker, sorry for inconvenience due to my bed English, But I just want to validate zipcode/pincode/postal code for any city. (may be this is different in various countries and cities), but my basic knowledge is, it should be accept alphabet and numbers with some special characters eg. space, hyphen and (). and this special characters must not be twice one after one (means '((' or '))' or '--' can't be acceptable.

Comment: Don't do this. How can you possibly know what a legal Zip code is for all the countries on earth? You can't perform any meaningful validation here, you will only annoy your users and prevent them from entering a valid code that you haven't thought of, and still allow them to enter invalid codes (for example, in Germany, postcode always have exactly five digits, no more, no less). Some countries may not have zipcodes at all.

Comment: that's fine. but still I need this validations because avoiding totally unused data in my system.

Comment: So you would prefer having wrong data to wasting a couple of bytes?

Comment: yes @Tim. no data is better then wrong data for my application.

Comment: I give up. You can change the regex to `/^(?! )(?!.*([ ()-])\1)[A-Za-z0-9 ()-]*$/` to avoid doubles like `--` or `((`, but you're still not going to achieve what you want. Even worse, you're getting a false sense of security, and you're still making it hard on your users unnecessarily.