# Add email and numerical validation to jquery form

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I have a very simple questionnaire form that only needs a few fields be mandatory. How can I add an email validation to the email field to confirm its an actual email. and how can I confirm that the zip_code contains only numbers? Also would be awesome if instead of using an alert I could use a div tag that would show up on the form and tell them what they need to fill out if anyone knows how to simply add that. I am using Twitter Bootstrap and would love to use their warning div's

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#contact_form').submit(function(){
        if ($('#first_name').val() == '') {
            alert('You must enter your first name!');           
            return false;
        }
        if ($('#last_name').val() == '') {
            alert('You must enter your last name!');
            return false;
        }
        if ($('#email').val() == '') {
            alert('You must enter an email!');
            return false;
        } 
        if ($('#zip_code').val() == '') {
            alert('You must enter your zip code!');
            return false;
        }  
        if ($('#message').val() == '') {
            alert('You need to tell us something! Please enter your message!');
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

**THE HTML**

```
<div class="error"></div>
<form id="contact_form" method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" placeholder="First Name"/>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" placeholder="Last Name"/>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email"/>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" name="zip_code" id="zip_code" placeholder="Zip Code"/>
    <br/>
    <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

**THE JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#contact_form').submit(function(){
        error = '';

        if ($('#first_name').val() == '') {
            error += 'You must enter your first name!<br/>';
        }

        if ($('#last_name').val() == '') {
            error += 'You must enter your last name!<br/>';
        }

        if ($('#email').val() == '') {
            error += 'You must enter your email<br/>';
        }
        else
        {
            var pattern = new RegExp(/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i);

            if(!pattern.test($('#email').val()))
            {
                error += "Invalid email address<br/>";
            }
        }

        if ($('#zip_code').val() == '') {
            error += 'You must enter your zip code<br/>';
        } 
        else
        {
            if (!isNumber($('#zip_code').val()))
            {
                error += 'Invalid zip code<br/>';
            }
        }
        if ($('#message').val() == '') {
            error += 'You need to tell us something! Please enter your message!';
        }

        if(error != '')
        {
            $('.error').html(error);
            $('.error').fadeIn();
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    });
});

function isNumber(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

**EXAMPLE**
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NUE9m/)

Comment: You da man that work perfectly as I needed it to. Master of your craft sir!

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer for validating your email field [Email validation using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507030/email-validation-using-jquery)

Check out this answer for Zip Code validation [ZIP Code (US Postal Code) validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160550/zip-code-us-postal-code-validation)

To output to bootstrap warning message put something like the following instead of your alerts...

```
 $(body).prepend('<div class="alert alert-block alert-error fade in"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">&times;</a>You need to tell us something! Please enter your message!</div>');
```