# regex for numbers comma and space

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text area and a user can input US zip codes in it separated by a comma or (comma and space).

It could be like 
12345,45678, 89654

The following regex is working and is removing not allowed characters:

```
$object.val($object.val().replace(/[^\d\, ]/g, ''));
```

I would like to enhance it, so that

1. i always should have 5 digits in the beginning
2. after 5 digits, there should be a comma or comma and space
3. comma or (comma and space) should not be at the very end of the string. It must be 5 digit number at the end.

This needs to tackle the copy paste as well. The user may copy paste invalid length for the zip code.

Thanks

Comment: Have you thought about the jQuery maskedinput plugin? It works great for me, and I've had no conflicts. http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Comment: have you tried searching SO for possible answers that could help you accomplish this? how about the one here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160550/zip-code-us-postal-code-validation/160583#160583

Comment: Instead of cropping input texts, I would recommend just to show when they are invalid.

Comment: You are ignoring the new 9 digit (preferred) zip code:12345-5432 . Is that a good idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this regex:
`^\d{5}(, ?\d{5})*$`

It specifies 5 digits at the beginning: `^\d{5}`
and any number of other comma, space, and 5 digit combinations: `(, ?\d{5})*`

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
var s='12345,45678, 12345';
var m = s.match(/^(?:\d{5},\s?)*\d{5}$/);
```

Comment: I need to restrict not allowed chars while the user is entering the numbers. This is good for validation on blur or submit.

Comment: Didn't get your comment. This will not allow any not-allowed character.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function Validate(txt) {
                txt.value = txt.value.replace(/[^, 0-9]+/g, '');
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type = "text" id ="txt" onkeyup = "Validate(this)" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: after, one space then 0-9