# Zipcode validation for US

Tags: javascript, php, validation

Can any one tell me how can i validate zipcode for US using regular expression.

I used below expression for validation

```
var us_postcode_regular = /^([0-9]{5})(?:[-\s]*([0-9]{4}))?$/;
```

However it is not able to validate all 00000 or 11111 or similar numbers.

and how can i validate the incorrect zipcode like the five digits which are not the part of US zipcode.

Comment: It's [**working for me.**](http://regexr.com?36itk)

Comment: That pattern is already correct. You cannot really determine valid zip codes from a regular expression; you can only tell if it's in the right form (5 or 9 digits).

Comment: If you want to make sure that the zip code exists, check out USPS's Address Validation API: https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/address-information.htm

Comment: What is wrong with doing this: `if(ctype_digit($zip) && strlen($zip) == 5){ echo 'US Zip Code'; }`

Comment: Great start to ensuring your data quality Satyendra - just watch out as not everyone has a 5 digit zip code! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22620156/making-sure-that-a-user-cant-submit-less-than-5-numbers-for-zip-code-in-a-javas/22631342#22631342 Al.

Comment: Try this discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160550/zip-code-us-postal-code-validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(ctype_digit($zip) && strlen($zip) == 5){ echo 'US Zip Code'; }
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.zipcodeapi.com/API#zipToLoc makes this very simple.  The call looks like:

```
http://www.zipcodeapi.com/rest/<api_key>/info.<format>/<zip_code>/<units>
```

Bad zipcodes will throw an error that you can catch. A valid zipcode will return a JSON (or XML or CSV) response look like:

```
{
"zip_code": "08057",
"lat": 56.595452,
"lng": -69.784543,
"city": "Classified",
"state": "NJ",
"timezone": {
    "timezone_identifier": "America/New_York",
    "timezone_abbr": "EDT",
    "utc_offset_sec": -14400,
    "is_dst": "T"
},
"acceptable_city_names": [
    {
        "city": "Classified",
        "state": "NJ"
    },
    {
        "city": "Classified",
        "state": "NJ"
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I belive, the simplest one you can use is this:

```
function validateUSAZip($zip_code) {
return preg_match(“/^([0-9]{5})(-[0-9]{4})?$/i”,$zip_code);
}
```

It is actually using similar regex like yours.

Answer (score -1):

```
<!-- Hi developers this is a simple demo for **zip code validation for us country** And this code is very usefull for you. -->

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Validate US Zip Code in JavaScript</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function IsValidZipCode(zip) {
            var isValid = /^[0-9]{5}(?:-[0-9]{4})?$/.test(zip);
            if (isValid)
                alert('Valid ZipCode');
            else {
                alert('Invalid ZipCode');
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body> 
<form>
<input id="txtZip" name="zip" type="text" /><br />
<input id="Button1" type="submit" value="Validate"onclick="IsValidZipCode(this.form.zip.value)" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

For more info.
http://www.devcurry.com/2010/07/validate-us-zip-code-using-javascript.html